# Detect whether RPScreenRecorder is recording

Tags: avplayer, ios11, rpscreenrecorder

In my application, I use `AVPlayer` to play videos. However, I do **not** use `FairPlay`.

I tried to use **RPScreenRecorder** to detect whether screen recording is on:

```
[RPScreenRecorder sharedRecorder].isRecording
```

but that does not work.

Does anyone know how to get whether screen recording is on?

Answer (score 0):

Get the window of your app delegate and check isCaptured:

```
[appDel.window.screen isCaptured]
```

That will indicate if anything is "using" the screen: RPScreenRecorder, airplay, or mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

Normally RPScreenRecorder is not compatible with AVplayer. That might be the cause of what you are going through

It is said in actual Documentation here: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit?language=objc)

> ReplayKit is incompatible with AVPlayer content.